# A trigonometric equation 1

Tags: trigonometry

$$4 \sin x \cos^3 x - 4 \sin^3 x \cos x = 1$$

I tried to multiply both members of the equations by $\frac{1}{\cos^4 x}$ and then say $\frac{1}{\cos^4 x} = (\tan^2 x + 1)^2$.
I ended up with the equation $$\tan^4 x + 4 \tan^3 x + 2 \tan^2 x -4 \tan x + 1 = 0$$ but I have to get to this answer: $\left\{\frac{\pi }{8}+\frac{k\pi }{2},\:k\:\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
4 \sin x \cos^3 x - 4 \sin^3 x \cos x &=& 1 \\
4 \sin x \cos x (\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x) &=& 1 \\
2 \sin 2x \cos 2x &=& 1 \\
\sin 4x &=& 1 \\
4x &\in& \left\{\dfrac\pi2 + 2k\pi : k \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
x &\in& \left\{(4k+1)\dfrac \pi8 : k \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

Using $\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A,\sin3A=3\sin A-4\sin^3A$ formula,

$$1=\sin x(\cos3x+3\cos x)+\cos x(\sin3x-3\sin x)=\sin(x+3x)$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

*Variant*:
$$4\sin x\cos^3x-4\sin^3x\cos x=2(2\sin x\cos x)(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)=2\sin 2x\cos  2x=\sin 4x=1.$$
The solutions are given by
$$4x\equiv \frac\pi2\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv\frac\pi8\mod\frac\pi2.$$

Comment: How is it different from the rest two answers?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing when other answers were being posted, and I didn't look if a similar answer was posted in the meantime. I'd say it's shorter and expressed in terms of congruences. Not fundamentally different though.

Comment: I actually expect something really unique whenever  u write an answer.

Comment: ?? The solution is not unique. Do you mean you don't like expressing solutions as congruences?

Comment: +1 for congruence representation, have you seen that anywhere or only you write like this?Asking because I am seeing it for the first time.

Comment: It's a very handy notation. I always used it on teaching, but of course it depends on the teaching level.

Answer (score 2):

The key isn't just solving this one problem, but being able to get to a lot of useful trig identities with a simple method.  de Moivre's theorem is a great method for this.

From Euler's theorem (which most people remember)

$e^{i \theta}=cos(\theta)+i sin(\theta)$

we can easily get de Moivre's theorem (since they are almost the same)

$(cos(\theta)+i sin(\theta))^n=cos(n \theta)+i sin(n \theta)$

If you use Pascal's triangle on the left hand side, you then get some nice trig identities.

$cos(4 \theta)+i sin(4 \theta)=(cos(\theta)+i sin(\theta))^4 $

I like to set up Pascal's triangle elements in rows.
\begin{matrix}
1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\
cos^4(\theta) & cos^3(\theta) & cos^2(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 1 \\
1 & sin(\theta) & sin^2(\theta) & sin^3(\theta) & sin^4(\theta) \\
1 & i & -1 & -i & 1
\end{matrix}

Multiplying the columns, we get

$cos^4(\theta)+ 4i cos^3(\theta)sin(\theta)-6 cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\theta)-4 i cos(\theta) sin^3(\theta)+sin^4(\theta)$

Equating the real to the real and the imaginary to the imaginary, we get

$cos(4\theta)=cos^4(\theta)-6 cos^2(\theta) sin^2(\theta)+sin^4(\theta)$

$sin(4\theta)=4 cos^3(\theta)sin(\theta)-4 cos(\theta) sin^3(\theta)$

Using this second identity, your problem comes out pretty quickly.

So generally, when you see numbers in a trig identity that remind you of Pascal's triangle, and powers that line up nice, your first thought should be to look for these sorts of identities.

---

Just a hint about how math teachers/instructors think.  If a problem like yours appears in the homework, you can bet that a problem involving something like

$cos(3\theta)=cos^3(\theta)-3 cos(\theta) sin^2(\theta)$

$sin(3\theta)=3 cos^2(\theta)sin(\theta)-sin^3(\theta)$

is likely to appear on the test.

And there's no sense in trying to memorize these guys if you can derive them in about a minute.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Observe that
\begin{align*}
4 \sin x \cos^3 x - 4 \sin^3 x \cos x &= 2(2\sin x\cos x)(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)\\
&=2\sin (2x)\cos (2x)\\
&=\sin (4x)
\end{align*}